# function returned undefined and promises is not defined in functions firebase

Tags: node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

This is my first firebase function and it gives me a lot of headic :) The purpose is to update the count field from all documents from collection users every 24 hours.

```
    async function clearCountField() {
  console.log("Clearing count task start point.");
    const userSnapshots = db.collection('users').where('count', '!=', '').where('nou', '==', false).get().then(snapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        promises.push(doc.ref.update({ 'count': '' }));
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
}



export const ClearCountField24h = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Bucharest') //  timezone 
  .onRun((context) => {
   const promise = clearCountField().then(resolve,reject); 
});
```

what do I do wrong?

Comment: You're not returning the `promise` from the `ClearCountField24h` function, so the Cloud Functions container has no knowledge about when the async operations compelte. Adding `return promise` to it should solve that.

Comment: Returning a promise from `ClearCountField24h` will not fix `clearCountField` trying to promise.all a variable defined/populated in a callback that happened in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises created in the `forEach` loop are never resolved because `Promise.all()` is being returned before the query completes. Fix it like this:

```
async function clearCountField() {
  const query = db.collection('users').where('count', '!=', '').where('nou', '==', false);
  return query.get().then(snapshot => {
    const promises = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({ 'count': '' }));
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
}
```

The `then` in your export function is superfluous. Just return the promise from `clearCountField()`

```
export const ClearCountField24h = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Bucharest') //  timezone 
  .onRun((context) => {
    return clearCountField();
});
```

Comment: it works, I only have to increase the memory allocation. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works. If you know that the 'users' table has some limit on its growth, you'll be fine tweaking the function resources like memory. An alternative would be to loop, putting a limit on the query and processing the docs in batches.

Comment: the users will only grow and be bigger and bigger, even with some cleanup there will be thousands of records, before i imported the data from a google sheet i had 14k records :)

Answer (score -1):

Changing the following:

```js
export const ClearCountField24h = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Bucharest') //  timezone 
  .onRun((context) => {
    const promise = clearCountField().then(resolve,reject); 
  }
);
```

To this:

```js
export const ClearCountField24h = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Bucharest') //  timezone 
  .onRun((context) => {
    return clearCountField().then(resolve,reject); 
  }
);
```

Made one issue go away... but when testing the function the `Error: ReferenceError: promises is not defined` still remains...